# MySQL JSON Extraction

Tags: java, mysql, sql, json, database

My question is the following: 
How can i extract a single entry of a JSON String. 
My JSON file looks like the following:

### What i have:

JSON FILE:

```
 [{ "ordnung" : 0, "value" : 0.006340 }, 
  { "ordnung" : 0.031250, "value" : 0.005271 },
  { "ordnung" : 0.062500, "value" : 0.000841 },
  { "ordnung" : 0.093750, "value" : 0.000049 },
  { "ordnung" : 0.125000, "value" : 0.000043 },
 ]
```

### JSON Text in MySQL Viewer:

```
[{"value": 0.0063400210399851675, "ordnung": 0}, {"value": 0.005271360498868513, "ordnung": 0.03125}, {"value": 0.0008408607792916407, "ordnung": 0.0625}, {"value": 0.00004851407472380133, "ordnung": 0.09375}, {"value": 0.000043459825197231685, "ordnung": 0.125}, {"value": 0.000034275530638516464, "ordnung": 0.15625}, {"value": 0.000029826783441950808, "ordnung": 0.1875}, {"value": 0.00003289378202360388, "ordnung": 0.21875}]
```

### What i see (snippet):

[image: MySQL Text View]

[image: MySQL JSON View]

### What i have tried:

I have tried SELECT *... WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(JSONColumn,'$**.ordnung') = 0.125000

and based on the solution of @wchiquito i tried:

```
SELECT
  JSON_ARRAY(
    JSON_EXTRACT(@`json`, REPLACE(
      JSON_UNQUOTE(
        JSON_SEARCH(REPLACE(
                      REPLACE(@`json`,
                              '"value": ',
                              '"value": "'),
                    ',"ordnung"',
                    '", "ordnung"'),
                    'one',
                    '0.125000',
                    NULL,
                    '$[*].ordnung')
      ), '.ordnung', '')
    )
  );
```

But this returns null

### What i want to get:

What i want to get is the single line:

```
[{"ordnung" : 0.125000, "value" : 0.000043 }]
```

### What i not want to use:

I will not iterate over a array in my application because of performance.

### Where i use it

I will use the data in some Java application to do statistics on this data

---

Does someone has an idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/zfnzBKD4Z2AntGq4V45Cv/0).

Comment: Thanks that works great for the given example. For some reason my JSON text does not look like the JSON object (at least in the viewer).  I have already adjusted the search for 0.125 instead of 0.125000. When the object is displayed, these zeros are added. However, they do not appear in the JSON string.



I copy the JSON text into the task description. I think a little adjustment should fix the problem. Unfortunately, my adjustments did not work. Whereby I have replaced the 'value' by 'order' and vice versa.

Comment: So i think the concrete question is how to switch 'value' and 'ordnung'. But i think you are the mysql JSON expert @wchiquito :-)

Comment: I post my try in the upper field once again based on your solution

Comment: To fully utilize the power of MySQL and JSON I strongly recommend to split the json into a new table and write one object per row. This way you can use virtual (indexed) fields for queries. Searching and manipulating the whole array on the fly seems horribly inefficient

Comment: Thanks, can you give a short example? You mean split the JSON Object on the fly, don´t you?

Comment: Okay, based on @wchiquito:

The answer would be:
SELECT
  JSON_ARRAY(
    JSON_EXTRACT(@`json`, REPLACE(
      JSON_UNQUOTE(
        JSON_SEARCH(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(@`json`,
                            '"ordnung": ',
                            '"ordnung":"'),
                        '}',
                        '"}'),
                    'one',
                    '0',
                    NULL,
                    '$[*].ordnung')
      ), '.ordnung', '')
    )
  );

Comment: Thanks to @wchiquito